# Drawing quantum optic diagrams using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone know of a package that handles quantum optics? I am just looking for a unified approach to handle drawing images like the following:

[image: example_image]

Comment: With `pstricks`, you have the `pst-optexp` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create this diagram, IMHO you do not need anything special. If you have several diagrams and you want to have them follow the same conventions, install some styles and create some pics.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
collector/.style={code={
\draw[fill=gray!20] (0,0.5) arc(90:-90:0.75cm and 0.5cm) -- cycle;}},
splitter/.style={code={\draw[ultra thick] (#1:{sqrt(1/2)}) --
(#1+180:{sqrt(1/2)});}},splitter/.default=135}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[->] (-1,0) node[left]{$\alpha_i$} -- (4,0) pic[right=1ex]{collector};
\draw[->] (0,1) node[above]{$\beta_1$} -- (0,-2.5) pic[below=1ex,rotate=-90]{collector};
\draw[->] (3,1) node[above]{$\beta_2$} -- (3,-1) pic[below=1ex,rotate=-90]{collector};
\draw[->] (-1,-1.5) node[left]{$\beta_3$} -- (1,-1.5) pic[right=1ex]{collector};
\path (0,0) pic{splitter} node[above right]{$\eta_1$}
 (3,0) pic{splitter} node[above right]{$\eta_2$}
  (0,-1.5) pic{splitter} node[above right]{$\eta_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I do not know much about (quantum) optics, so it is more than likely that there are better names for the pics.

Comment: The `\tikzset`. I like how you defined the splitter.