# Creating a node for an optical splitter

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

Could you please help me creating a node of an optical splitter, that has two input ports and two output ports? The shape is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

% Draw lines
\draw (-2,1)  to [out=0,in=180] (0,0);
\draw (-2,-1) to [out=0,in=180] (0,0);
\draw (0,0)   to [out=0,in=180] (2,1);
\draw (0,0)   to [out=0,in=180] (2,-1);

% Draw center ellipse
\filldraw (0,0) ellipse (0.2 and 0.1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `pic` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please add a full compileable code.

Comment: Thank you, done!

Comment: Thank you, what is an optical splitter? What are the characteristics that this node must have?

Comment: I agree with @Fractal. An example for defining a pic of that name can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520837/194703). Of course, you need to put in your code and give the coordinates names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `pic`. IMHO in this case a `pic` is more appropriate than a `node` (after all, what will you write right at the center of the splitter?)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[optical splitter/.pic = {
  \draw[pic actions] (-2,1) coordinate (#1-in-1) to [out=0,in=180] (0,0)
    (-2,-1) coordinate (#1-in-2) to [out=0,in=180] (0,0)
    (0,0)   to [out=0,in=180] (2,1) coordinate (#1-out-1)
    (0,0)   to [out=0,in=180] (2,-1) coordinate (#1-out-2);
  \filldraw[pic actions] (0,0) ellipse (0.2 and 0.1);
}]
  \pic[red] at (0,0) {optical splitter=X};
  \draw[blue] (-3,-2) |- (X-in-1);
  \draw[purple] (X-in-2) -- ++ (0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That will do, thank you!